# Android pattern on top of 9patched BG png

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to know if there is any easy way to apply this pattern:

[image]

on top of this background:

[image]

The problem is that the BG has borders, so the pattern cant get outside or be on top of the borders. It has to be exactly inside of the borders. Maybe this isn't even possible.

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: this is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. please show an example.

Comment: I have a put an image that shows what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired result, you can do the following:

**1.** Create a `FrameLayout` and set the the yellow image as it's background, set it width and height to `match_parent`.

**2.** Next, place an `ImageView` inside the `FrameLayout` created in step 1 and set the gray image as the source of this `ImageView`, you may want to create a transparent gray image (if this one isn't) to see the content behind it. Set the width and height of this `ImageView` to `match_parent` as well.

**3.** Set suitable layout margins for the `ImageView` to handle the borders of the yellow image properly.

Something like this:

```
 <FrameLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/yellow_image" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/gray_semitransperent_image"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />
 <FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Layer-List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) by making an xml file in drawable folder. It is easy to use same as a background drawable. Lets make a file name bg.xml in drawable folder:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right:"1dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pattern"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In above lines we've added a Bitmap with repeat and offset of 1 dp (or whatever suits you.) and the second one is your bitmap which is 9 patch image. *(You may need to change their order to make other item visilbe., as I don't have eclipse at the moment)*
And to use it in your view, do something like this.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        />
```